# Notation question in linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

I am confused by the symbol $\mathcal{L}$. What do $\mathcal{L}(V)$ and (especially) $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(V),\mathcal{L}(W))$ in b) mean?

> Let $T:V\to W$ be an isomorphism. For each $S\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ we define $\phi(S)=T\circ S\circ T^{-1}.$
>
> a) Prove that $T\circ S\circ T^{-1}\in\mathcal{L}(W).$ (you should show that it maps vectors of $W$ to vectors of $W,$ and that it is linear)
>
> b) Prove that $\phi\in
> \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(V),\mathcal{L}(W)).$ (you just showed that $\phi$ maps vectors of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ to vectors of $\mathcal{L}(W),$ so it is sufficient to show that $\phi$ is linear)
>
> c) Prove that $\phi$ is a bijection.
>
> d) Prove that $\phi(RS)=\phi(R)\phi(S)$ for any $R,S\in\mathcal{L}(V).$

Comment: $\mathcal{L}(V)$ usually stands for the set of all linear operators on $V$ (that is, linear transformations from $V$ to $V$).

Comment: So L(L(v),L(w)) means linear transformations form V to W ?

Comment: @Hao No, it means the set of linear transformations from $L(v)$ to $L(w)$. That is, a linear transformation that sends a linear transformation to a linear transformation.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! I took the liberty of retagging your question. Before creating new tags, please check if there is some synonym that already has a popular tag. (If you disagree with the removal of the tag you've created, there is possibility for further discussion, if needed.) For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, given vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ over a given field, $\mathcal L(X)$ is the set of linear transformations $X\to X$, and $\mathcal L(X,Y)$ is the set of linear transformations $X\to Y$. Noting that $\mathcal L(V)$ and $\mathcal L(W)$ are vector spaces over a given field whenever $V$ and $W$ are, we have in particular that $\mathcal L(\mathcal L(V),\mathcal L(W))$ is the set of linear transformations $\mathcal L(V)\to\mathcal L(W)$.